# Octopus Deploy and "Add Web Service Reference" / New-WebServiceProxy timeout

Tags: c#, powershell, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, octopus-deploy

Working with Octopus Deploy, trying to deploy our SSRS reports packages. I used a community powershell script, which uses `New-WebServiceProxy` to create proxies for the report server web services so that it can upload reports etc.

Found that we have intermittent timeouts when calling `New-WebServiceProxy`. Sometimes it will come back immediately, sometimes will timeout 2 or 3 times in a row.

We checked all the usual things

- making sure the site was running (not cold) when making the call etc.
- different users with the right permissions
- Creating a fresh SSRS isntance on a different server

No change.

As a final step in debugging, I created a console app in visual studio with the intention of adding the web service proxies there and replicating the functionaly of the powershell script (as a test).

Going to Add Service Reference --> Add Web Service Reference" in Visual Studio gives identical behaviour (after pasting in the URL and clicking the navigate/go button) as the `New-WebServiceProxy` call in powershell.

Sometimes this timed out or hung (requiring a VS restart). Sometimes it worked quickly.

Because of this, I'm wondering

- Is there any known issue with these methods of creating web service proxies.
- Has anyone else found intermittant timeouts when doing this? (I found mention of similar hangs / crahses in VS, but no answers).

Once the reference was added in Visual Studio, actual use of the proxy was quick and easy.

- Is there a way to create a web service proxy in Powershell from a fixed definition (not from the URL) and still be able to change the target URL?
- Is there a way to persist the proxy, or to use one generated in C#?

Any other suggestions gratefully received.

**Update**

Could this be user account related? If I run:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://ssrs-server.domain/ReportServer/reportservice2010.asmx?wsdl -UseDefaultCredential -UseBasicParsing -OutFile ReportService2010.wsdl
```

on my local machine, or on the deployment tenticle logged in as myself, it comes back near instantly. If I run it via Octopus deploy console, it takes randomly between 1 and 3 minutes to complete.

Any ideas on why this should take so long when running in that context?

Comment: i had the same issue a while ago, always thought the Server had issue...

Comment: This has been driving me nuts for ages now. We have a "working" deployment solution which we can't use because it randomly doesn't work about 50% of the time.

Comment: I dont have reporting services to test, but ... The default setup for the tentacle is to run as Local System, non-interactive.  Either of these alone would be different than running as you.  To test your theory, in the service manager, change the user for the "OctopusDeploy Tentacle" service to your username/password and allow it interact with desktop.  Then go from there.